# How to configure GeneratedFileFilters of SonarC# to allow generated files

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I would like to analyze a C# project with SonarQube. Some of my files have `*.g.cs` extension. Sonar C# plugin handles those files as if they are generated files and I get this error:

> 'SomeDirectory/ETitle.g.cs' excluded by org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.GeneratedFileFilter

How can I include those files to sonar scan?

Comment: They aren't automatically generated? Typically `*.g.cs` is just that, generated files.

Comment: As a said, this is a naming convention we defined 5 years ago

Comment: You might be able to explicitly include them. But since you're using a standard extension for something it's not meant for, it might not work

Answer (score 0):

The analysis of generated C# files can be enabled using the SonarQube or SonarCloud UI, in Project > Administration > General Settings > C#, and enabling the *Analyze generated code* option.